# One source of truth for model and factory

Tags: python, factory, faker, factory-boy

I am finding myself writing the same code a lot when type hinting the JSON response of an API e.g:

```
class Foo(TypedDict):
    foo: int
    baz: str
```

from a json response:

```
{
   'foo': 1,
   'baz': 'somestr'
}
```

I am now wanting to write some factories so I can mock and test this endpoint. So I have to write a pretty similar:

```
class FooFactory(factory.DictFactory):
    foo = Faker("random_int")
    baz = Faker("text")
```

Which is quite a pain to have to maintain them both. Is there no way I can have the factory use `Foo` as "inspiration" - *i.e the type hint is `str` so use `Faker("text")`, the type hint is `int` so use `Faker("random_int")` etc...* ?

I have tried:

```
class FooFactory(factory.DictFactory):
    class Meta:
       model = Foo
```

But this doesn't really seem to do anything of note - in that it just returns `{}` in my tests.

---

Also I am not restricted to `TypedDicts` or factoryboy. I just don't want to write the same thing twice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a planned feature for factory_boy, see https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy/issues/836.

That issue points to draft implementations which could be reused in your code, by subclassing the `Factory` class.

Comment: Hello! Thank you - which bit of code are you referring to specifically sorry?

Comment: All those pointed in the "Existing work" section, notably https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy/commit/4046c55710d5d7073018dcc76aa3e8e5a7f803eb and https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy/issues/330